# hiding radio buttons until condition is met

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am self taught when it comes to Javascript/html and i cant get my radio buttons to hide until a item is crafted  https://jsfiddle.net/tmanrocks999/dfroan50/32/      I basically want all the radio buttons hidden except the first row (Woodsword, leather helm,leather boots, leather armor)

I do have a function in this fiddle that i wanted to use but it seems to not work. If someone can help me get all my radio buttons except the first row to be hidden until the item is crafted I would really appreciate it.

```js
var Strength = 0;
var Magic = 0;
var ManaPoints = 0;
var HitPoints = 0;
var StoredStrengthe = Strength;
var StoredMagic = Magic;
var StoredManaPoints = ManaPoints;
var StoredHitPoints = HitPoints;

function woodsworde() {
  if (document.getElementById("woodsword").checked) {
    Strength = Strength + 1;
    document.getElementById("Strength").innerHTML = Strength;
  } else {
    Strength = StoredStrengthe
    document.getElementById("Strength").innerHTML = Strength;

  }
}

function silversworde() {
  if (document.getElementById("silversword").checked) {
    Strength = Strength + 3;
    document.getElementById("Strength").innerHTML = Strength;
  } else {
    Strength = StoredStrengthe
    document.getElementById("Strength").innerHTML = Strength;

  }
}

function goldsworde() {
  if (document.getElementById("goldsword").checked) {
    Strength = Strength + 5;
    document.getElementById("Strength").innerHTML = Strength;
  } else {
    Strength = StoredStrengthe
    document.getElementById("Strength").innerHTML = Strength;

  }
}

function diamondsworde() {
  if (document.getElementById("diamondsword").checked) {
    Strength = Strength + 10;
    document.getElementById("Strength").innerHTML = Strength;
  } else {
    Strength = StoredStrengthe
    document.getElementById("Strength").innerHTML = Strength;

  }
}



function leatherhelme() {
  if (document.getElementById("leatherhelm").checked) {
    Magic = Magic + 1;
    document.getElementById("Magic").innerHTML = Magic;
  } else {
    Magic = StoredMagic
    document.getElementById("Magic").innerHTML = Magic;

  }
}

function silverhelme() {
  if (document.getElementById("silverhelm").checked) {
    Magic = Magic + 3;
    document.getElementById("Magic").innerHTML = Magic;
  } else {
    Magic = StoredMagic
    document.getElementById("Magic").innerHTML = Magic;

  }
}

function goldhelme() {
  if (document.getElementById("goldhelm").checked) {
    Magic = Magic + 5;
    document.getElementById("Magic").innerHTML = Magic;
  } else {
    Magic = StoredMagic
    document.getElementById("Magic").innerHTML = Magic;

  }
}

function diamondhelme() {
  if (document.getElementById("diamondhelm").checked) {
    Magic = Magic + 10;
    document.getElementById("Magic").innerHTML = Magic;
  } else {
    Magic = StoredMagic
    document.getElementById("Magic").innerHTML = Magic;

  }
}


function leatherbootse() {
  if (document.getElementById("leatherboots").checked) {
    ManaPoints = ManaPoints + 3;
    document.getElementById("ManaPoints").innerHTML = ManaPoints;
  } else {
    ManaPoints = StoredManaPoints
    document.getElementById("ManaPoints").innerHTML = ManaPoints;

  }
}

function silverbootse() {
  if (document.getElementById("silverboots").checked) {
    ManaPoints = ManaPoints + 5;
    document.getElementById("ManaPoints").innerHTML = ManaPoints;
  } else {
    ManaPoints = StoredManaPoints
    document.getElementById("ManaPoints").innerHTML = ManaPoints;

  }
}

function goldbootse() {
  if (document.getElementById("goldboots").checked) {
    ManaPoints = ManaPoints + 10;
    document.getElementById("ManaPoints").innerHTML = ManaPoints;
  } else {
    ManaPoints = StoredManaPoints
    document.getElementById("ManaPoints").innerHTML = ManaPoints;

  }
}

function diamondbootse() {
  if (document.getElementById("diamondboots").checked) {
    ManaPoints = ManaPoints + 15;
    document.getElementById("ManaPoints").innerHTML = ManaPoints;
  } else {
    ManaPoints = StoredManaPoints
    document.getElementById("ManaPoints").innerHTML = ManaPoints;

  }
}


function leatherarmore() {
  if (document.getElementById("leatherarmor").checked) {
    HitPoints = HitPoints + 1;
    document.getElementById("HitPoints").innerHTML = HitPoints;
  } else {
    HitPoints = StoredHitPoints
    document.getElementById("HitPoints").innerHTML = HitPoints;

  }
}

function silverarmore() {
  if (document.getElementById("silverarmor").checked) {
    HitPoints = HitPoints + 3;
    document.getElementById("HitPoints").innerHTML = HitPoints;
  } else {
    HitPoints = StoredHitPoints
    document.getElementById("HitPoints").innerHTML = HitPoints;

  }
}

function goldarmore() {
  if (document.getElementById("goldarmor").checked) {
    HitPoints = HitPoints + 5;
    document.getElementById("HitPoints").innerHTML = HitPoints;
  } else {
    HitPoints = StoredHitPoints
    document.getElementById("HitPoints").innerHTML = HitPoints;

  }
}

function diamondarmore() {
  if (document.getElementById("diamondarmor").checked) {
    HitPoints = HitPoints + 10;
    document.getElementById("HitPoints").innerHTML = HitPoints;
  } else {
    HitPoints = StoredHitPoints
    document.getElementById("HitPoints").innerHTML = HitPoints;

  }
}

document.getElementById("woodsword").addEventListener("change",
  silversworde);
document.getElementById("woodsword").addEventListener("change",
  woodsworde);
document.getElementById("silversword").addEventListener("change",
  woodsworde);
document.getElementById("silversword").addEventListener("change",
  silversworde);
document.getElementById("goldsword").addEventListener("change",
  woodsworde);
document.getElementById("goldsword").addEventListener("change",
  goldsworde);
document.getElementById("diamondsword").addEventListener("change",
  woodsworde);
document.getElementById("diamondsword").addEventListener("change",
  diamondsworde);
document.getElementById("Strength").innerHTML = Strength;


document.getElementById("leatherhelm").addEventListener("change",
  silverhelme);
document.getElementById("leatherhelm").addEventListener("change",
  leatherhelme);
document.getElementById("silverhelm").addEventListener("change",
  leatherhelme);
document.getElementById("silverhelm").addEventListener("change",
  silverhelme);
document.getElementById("goldhelm").addEventListener("change",
  leatherhelme);
document.getElementById("goldhelm").addEventListener("change", goldhelme);
document.getElementById("diamondhelm").addEventListener("change",
  leatherhelme);
document.getElementById("diamondhelm").addEventListener("change",
  diamondhelme);
document.getElementById("Magic").innerHTML = Magic;

document.getElementById("leatherboots").addEventListener("change",
  silverbootse);
document.getElementById("leatherboots").addEventListener("change",
  leatherbootse);
document.getElementById("silverboots").addEventListener("change",
  leatherbootse);
document.getElementById("silverboots").addEventListener("change",
  silverbootse);
document.getElementById("goldboots").addEventListener("change",
  leatherbootse);
document.getElementById("goldboots").addEventListener("change",
  goldbootse);
document.getElementById("diamondboots").addEventListener("change",
  leatherbootse);
document.getElementById("diamondboots").addEventListener("change",
  diamondbootse);
document.getElementById("ManaPoints").innerHTML = ManaPoints;



document.getElementById("leatherarmor").addEventListener("change",
  silverarmore);
document.getElementById("leatherarmor").addEventListener("change",
  leatherarmore);
document.getElementById("silverarmor").addEventListener("change",
  leatherarmore);
document.getElementById("silverarmor").addEventListener("change",
  silverarmore);
document.getElementById("goldarmor").addEventListener("change",
  leatherarmore);
document.getElementById("goldarmor").addEventListener("change",
  goldarmore);
document.getElementById("diamondarmor").addEventListener("change",
  leatherarmore);
document.getElementById("diamondarmor").addEventListener("change",
  diamondarmore);
document.getElementById("HitPoints").innerHTML = HitPoints;



var silversword = 0;
document.getElementById("silversword").innerHTML = silversword;
var silverhelm = 0;
var silverboots = 0;
var silverarmor = 0;
var Silver = 500;
document.getElementById("Silver").innerHTML = Silver;
var goldsword = 0;
document.getElementById("goldsword").innerHTML = goldsword;
var goldhelm = 0;
var goldboots = 0;
var goldarmor = 0;
var Gold = 2000;
document.getElementById("Gold").innerHTML = Gold;
var diamondsword = 0;
document.getElementById("diamondsword").innerHTML = diamondsword;
var diamondhelm = 0;
var diamondboots = 0;
var diamondarmor = 0;
var Diamond = 10000;
document.getElementById("Diamond").innerHTML = Diamond;

function buySsword() {
  if (Silver >= 500) {
    Silver = Silver - 500;
    silversword = silversword + 1;
    document.getElementById("Silver").innerHTML = Silver;
    document.getElementById("silversword").innerHTML = silversword;
  }
  checkcraft()
}

function buyGsword() {
  if (Gold >= 2000) {
    Gold = Gold - 2000;
    goldsword = goldsword + 1;
    document.getElementById("Gold").innerHTML = Gold;
    document.getElementById("goldsword").innerHTML = goldsword;
  }
  checkcraft()
}

function buyDsword() {
  if (Diamond >= 10000) {
    Diamond = Diamond - 10000;
    diamondsword = diamondsword + 1;
    document.getElementById("Diamond").innerHTML = Diamond;
    document.getElementById("diamondsword").innerHTML = diamondsword;
  }
  checkcraft()
}

function buyShelm() {
  if (Silver >= 500) {
    Silver = Silver - 500;
    silverhelm = silverhelm + 1;
    document.getElementById("Silver").innerHTML = Silver;
    document.getElementById("silverhelm").innerHTML = silverhelm;
  }
  checkcraft()
}

function buyGhelm() {
  if (Gold >= 2000) {
    Gold = Gold - 2000;
    goldhelm = goldhelm + 1;
    document.getElementById("Gold").innerHTML = Gold;
    document.getElementById("goldhelm").innerHTML = goldhelm;
  }
  checkcraft()
}

function buyDhelm() {
  if (Diamond >= 10000) {
    Diamond = Diamond - 10000;
    diamondhelm = diamondhelm + 1;
    document.getElementById("Diamond").innerHTML = Diamond;
    document.getElementById("diamondhelm").innerHTML = diamondhelm;
  }
  checkcraft()
}

function buySboots() {
  if (Silver >= 500) {
    Silver = Silver - 500;
    silverboots = silverboots + 1;
    document.getElementById("Silver").innerHTML = Silver;
    document.getElementById("silverboots").innerHTML = silverboots;
  }
  checkcraft()
}

function buyGboots() {
  if (Gold >= 2000) {
    Gold = Gold - 2000;
    goldboots = goldboots + 1;
    document.getElementById("Gold").innerHTML = Gold;
    document.getElementById("goldboots").innerHTML = goldboots;
  }
  checkcraft()
}

function buyDboots() {
  if (Diamond >= 10000) {
    Diamond = Diamond - 10000;
    diamondboots = diamondboots + 1;
    document.getElementById("Diamond").innerHTML = Diamond;
    document.getElementById("diamondboots").innerHTML = diamondboots;
  }
  checkcraft()
}

function buySarmor() {
  if (Silver >= 500) {
    Silver = Silver - 500;
    silverarmor = silverarmor + 1;
    document.getElementById("Silver").innerHTML = Silver;
    document.getElementById("silverarmor").innerHTML = silverarmor;
  }
  checkcraft()
}

function buyGarmor() {
  if (Gold >= 2000) {
    Gold = Gold - 2000;
    goldarmor = goldarmor + 1;
    document.getElementById("Gold").innerHTML = Gold;
    document.getElementById("goldarmor").innerHTML = goldarmor;
  }
  checkcraft()
}

function buyDarmor() {
  if (Diamond >= 10000) {
    Diamond = Diamond - 10000;
    diamondarmor = diamondarmor + 1;
    document.getElementById("Diamond").innerHTML = Diamond;
    document.getElementById("diamondarmor").innerHTML = diamondarmor;
  }
  checkcraft()
}


function checkcraft() {
  if (silversword < 1) {
    document.getElementById("SilverSwordBtn").disabled = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("SilverSwordBtn").disabled = true;
  }
  if (goldsword < 1) {
    document.getElementById("GoldSwordBtn").disabled = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("GoldSwordBtn").disabled = true;
  }
  if (diamondsword < 1) {
    document.getElementById("DiamondSwordBtn").disabled = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("DiamondSwordBtn").disabled = true;
  }
  if (silverhelm < 1) {
    document.getElementById("SilverHelmBtn").disabled = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("SilverHelmBtn").disabled = true;
  }
  if (goldhelm < 1) {
    document.getElementById("GoldHelmBtn").disabled = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("GoldHelmBtn").disabled = true;
  }
  if (diamondhelm < 1) {
    document.getElementById("DiamondHelmBtn").disabled = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("DiamondHelmBtn").disabled = true;
  }
  if (silverboots < 1) {
    document.getElementById("SilverBootsBtn").disabled = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("SilverBootsBtn").disabled = true;
  }
  if (goldboots < 1) {
    document.getElementById("GoldBootsBtn").disabled = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("GoldBootsBtn").disabled = true;
  }
  if (diamondboots < 1) {
    document.getElementById("DiamondBootsBtn").disabled = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("DiamondBootsBtn").disabled = true;
  }
  if (silverarmor < 1) {
    document.getElementById("SilverArmorBtn").disabled = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("SilverArmorBtn").disabled = true;
  }
  if (goldarmor < 1) {
    document.getElementById("GoldArmorBtn").disabled = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("GoldArmorBtn").disabled = true;
  }
  if (diamondarmor < 1) {
    document.getElementById("DiamondArmorBtn").disabled = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("DiamondArmorBtn").disabled = true;
  }
}

checkcraft()


var silverswordr = document.getElementById('silverswordr');
var goldswordr = document.getElementById('goldswordr');
var diamondswordr = document.getElementById('diamondswordr');

function checkWunlock() {
  if (silversword < 1) {
    silverswordr.style.visibility = 'hidden'
  } else {
    silverswordr.style.visibility = 'visible'
  }
  if (goldsword < 1) {
    goldswordr.style.visibility = 'hidden'
  } else {
    goldswordr.style.visibility = 'visible'
  }
  if (diamondsword < 1) {
    diamondswordr.style.visibility = 'hidden'
  } else {
    diamondswordr.style.visibility = 'visible'
  }

}

checkWunlock()

//document.getElementById("").addEventListener("change", checkWunlock);
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title> Basic Clicker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="nav_bar">
    <ul>
      <li id="HomeTab"><a href="GameMainWindow.html">Home</a></li>
      <li id="SkillTreeTab"><a href="SkillTree.html">SkillTree</a></li>
      <li id="EquipmentTab"><a href="Equipment.html" id="onlink">Equipment</a></li>
      <li id="PetsTab"><a href="Pets.html">Pets</a></li>
      <li id="SkillsTab"><a href="Skills.html">Skills</a></li>
      <li id="QuestsTab"><a href="Quests.html">Quests</a></li>
      <li id="ShopTab"><a href="Shop.html">Shop</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="main_container">

    <div id="Equipmentradios" style="width: 500px; float:left; ">
      <p>
        <font size="+2"> <b> Equipment </b></font>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
        <br />
        <br /> Wood Sword<input id="woodsword" type="radio" name="Sword"> Silver Sword<input id="silversword" type="radio" name="Sword"> Gold Sword<input id="goldsword" type="radio" name="Sword"> Diamond Sword<input id="diamondsword" type="radio" name="Sword">
        <label class="radio">
                <br>
            Leather Helm <input id="leatherhelm"   type="radio" name="Helm">
            Silver Helm <input id="silverhelm"   type="radio" name="Helm">
            Gold Helm <input id="goldhelm"   type="radio" name="Helm">
            Diamond Helm <input id="diamondhelm"   type="radio" name="Helm">
                <label class="radio">
                <br>
            Leather Boots <input id="leatherboots"   type="radio" name="Boots">
            Silver Boots <input id="silverboots"   type="radio" name="Boots">
            Gold Boots <input id="goldboots"   type="radio" name="Boots">
            Diamond Boots <input id="diamondboots"   type="radio" name="Boots">
                <label class="radio">
                <br>
            Leather Armor <input id="leatherarmor"   type="radio" name="Armor">
            Silver Armor <input id="silverarmor"   type="radio" name="Armor">
            Gold Armor <input id="goldarmor"   type="radio" name="Armor">
            Diamond Armor <input id="diamondarmor"   type="radio" name="Armor">
                <label class="radio">
                <br>
                    </div>
                    
            <div id="crafting" style="width: 350px;   float:right;position: absolute; left: 650px; top: 115px; border: 15px solid green; height:300px; background:white; position: absolute; left: 600px; top: 115px; margin:10px">
                    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <font size="+2"> <b>Forge</b>
                    <br />
                    <font size="-2"> Silver Sword &nbsp;<button id="SilverSwordBtn" onclick="buySsword()">Craft</button> <font size="-2"> Gold Sword &nbsp;<button id="GoldSwordBtn" onclick="buyGsword()">Craft</button> <font size="-2"> Diamond Sword &nbsp;<button id="DiamondSwordBtn" onclick="buyDsword()">Craft</button>
                    <br />
                    <font size="-2"> Silver Helm &nbsp; &nbsp;<button id="SilverHelmBtn" onclick="buyShelm()">Craft</button> <font size="-2"> Gold Helm &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button id="GoldHelmBtn" onclick="buyGhelm()">Craft</button> <font size="-2"> Diamond Helm &nbsp;&nbsp;<button id="DiamondHelmBtn" onclick="buyDhelm()">Craft</button>
                    <br />
                    <font size="-2"> Silver Boots &nbsp;&nbsp;<button id="SilverBootsBtn" onclick="buySboots()">Craft</button> <font size="-2"> Gold Boots &nbsp;&nbsp;<button id="GoldBootsBtn" onclick="buyGboots()">Craft</button> <font size="-2"> Diamond Boots &nbsp;<button id="DiamondBootsBtn" onclick="buyDboots()">Craft</button>
                    <br />
                    <font size="-2"> Silver Armor &nbsp;<button id="SilverArmorBtn" onclick="buySarmor()">Craft</button> <font size="-2"> Gold Armor &nbsp;&nbsp;<button id="GoldArmorBtn" onclick="buyGarmor()">Craft</button> <font size="-2"> Diamond Armor &nbsp;<button id="DiamondArmorBtn" onclick="buyDarmor()">Craft</button>
                    <br />
                    Strength+<span id="Strength">0</span>
                    Magic+<span id="Magic">0</span>
                    ManaPoints+<span id="ManaPoints">0</span>
                    HitPoints+<span id="HitPoints">0</span>
                    <br />
                    Silver= <span id="Silver">0</span>  <span id="silversword">0</span>
                    <br />
                    Gold= <span id="Gold">0</span>     <span id="goldsword">0</span>
                    <br />
                    Diamond= <span id="Diamond">0</span>  <span id="diamondsword">0</span>
                        </div>
                    
                   
       
        
                    
                <script type="text/javascript" src="Pets.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="Equipment.js"></script>
                <p>
     </div>

    </body></html>
```

Everything should be in that fiddle. What i tried is at the very button with checkWunlock for checking if weapon is crafted or not. I expect all my radio buttons except the first row to be hidden until crafted, but the actual output all my radio buttons are visible making it so the player can use any equipment at the start. My disabling of the craft buttons work so im confused on why the hidden stuff wont work as well. If i can get a working way to hide my radio buttons id appreciate it.

Comment: This quite a lot of codes. You might wanna only include the relevant codes.

Comment: its everything. radio buttons need to be tied to being crafted. I guess i could remove what the radio buttons do. but they should be hidden until there respected thing is crafted then i want them to be working so being able to test that they do what they need to after being crafted/ unhidden helps.  I have this above but this fiddle is editable . I would prefer something similar to what i tried to hide the radio buttons  https://jsfiddle.net/tmanrocks999/dfroan50/32/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified your code.

html

```
<input type="radio" name="Type" value="flat" id="flatRadio" />Wood Sword
<input type="radio" name="Type" value="salary" id="salaryRadio" />Silver Sword

<br />
<div id="wordSword" class="options">Wood Sword:
    Leather Helm <input id="leatherhelm"   type="radio" name="Helm">
            Silver Helm <input id="silverhelm"   type="radio" name="Helm">
            Gold Helm <input id="goldhelm"   type="radio" name="Helm">
            Diamond Helm <input id="diamondhelm"   type="radio" name="Helm"></div>
<div id="silverSword" class="options">Silver Sword:
     Leather Boots <input id="leatherboots"   type="radio" name="Boots">
            Silver Boots <input id="silverboots"   type="radio" name="Boots">
            Gold Boots <input id="goldboots"   type="radio" name="Boots">
            Diamond Boots <input id="diamondboots"   type="radio" name="Boots"></div>
```

css

```
.options {
display:none;
```

for more code go to [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/shahjihan78/cp6wxfh8/15/) for full code

Hope can help you

Comment: Thanks man giving it a look now. this seams way out of my league tho. None of my whole game has anything like this. http://prntscr.com/or4cl3   i have this for a diffrent part and it works but not for a radio button just a span. http://prntscr.com/or4crt  keeps the inventory items under bronze and shrimp hidden( i have other code to keep from acquiring) until a condition is met. this is what i tried to follow for my radio buttons

Comment: So i basically need to put in that display option in css and use none and a different keyword to reveal the items?

Comment: from the 2 screenshots i linked in comments why does that format work but when try to do that with my radio buttons they dont.

Comment: Try you run your code at [https://jsfiddle.net/](https://jsfiddle.net/). Than I will try to fix your code

Comment: i got it a bit to work but when i try to follow my same format ( my html sucks u can edit it if u want)  https://jsfiddle.net/tmanrocks999/dfroan50/37/ this is my first attempt  https://jsfiddle.net/tmanrocks999/dfroan50/40/  this one i messed up the html part alot but is what i want cept i cant get the function i set up to work for the last 3 lines. so everything should be hidden cept the first line of equipment.

Comment: my html is very bad if u want to edit it but id prefer that format. with the big equipment word, a space then sword line, space, and so on.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/osc0tu  so this then http://prntscr.com/osc10k  this for each line should make it work. but it reveals everything and i dont get the output i want

Comment: http://prntscr.com/osc1cf  then i have this for when item is crafted. it checks the function then unlocks it

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tmanrocks999/dfroan50/42/  i got it to work but it only seams to work when i have                                                                                   
http://prntscr.com/osc7j6     the spans with silversword and silverhelm. i would prefer not the have those 0s on my program even remove the amount of silver,gold,diamonds u have

Comment: final edit https://jsfiddle.net/tmanrocks999/dfroan50/43/   if u can make this work without the spans i have in my html at the bottom that go up by 1 when the item is craft id really appreciate it. it works but i don't want those 0s in my craft box and it seams to only work when they are there